# How to prevent my node label from getting displaced to the left?

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,4)
    \pstGeonode(1,1){A_i}
    \pstGeonode[PointName=A_j](1,2){Aj}
    \pstGeonode[PointName=R_{i,j,k,l}](1,3){Rijkl}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to prevent my node label `R_{i,j,k,l}` from getting displaced to the left without using `PointNameSep`?

Comment: It seems to be [a bug](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/3/b/d/1194985428453820625bug_nicu_buculei_01.svg.med.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is not a bug, but an unidentified feature ;)

You can define a new key, e.g. `PointNameAlign` and redefine `\Pst@PutPointLabel` to use this key as alignment parameter for `\rput`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{pst-eucl}{PointNameAlign}{\edef\psk@PointNameAlign{#1}}%
\psset[pst-eucl]{PointNameAlign=c}
\def\Pst@PutPointLabel#1{%DR 041104
  \ifx\psk@PointName\@none\else
    \rput[\psk@PointNameAlign]{*0}([nodesep=\ifx\psk@PointNameSep\@default{1em}\else\psk@PointNameSep\fi,
               angle=\ifx\psk@PosAngle\@undef{0}\else\psk@PosAngle\fi]#1)%
      {\ifPst@PtNameMath$\Pst@WhichLabel{#1}$\else\Pst@WhichLabel{#1}\fi}
  \fi}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(3,4)
  \psset[pst-eucl]{PointNameAlign=l}
  \pstGeonode(1,1){A_i}
  \pstGeonode[PointName=A_j](1,2){Aj}
  \pstGeonode[PointName=R_{i,j,k,l}](1,3){Rijkl}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The only difference to the original definition is the `[\psk@PointNameAlign]`.

[image]

Comment: Because without specifying an alignment, `\rput` places the content centered at the given coordinates, which is what you see in your example.

Comment: They are centered at a distance of `1em` (default value of `PointNameSep`) and an angle of `0` degree (`PosAngle`) from the actual node.

Comment: When the label is a bit longer, it extends more to both left and right and finally overlaps with the dot...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that, as I understand it, the placement of labels relies on `\rput`. The default value of `PointNameSep` is 1em, and then the label itself is placed on the `left` of the position so defined. It should be on the right for labels at the right of the point, and on the left for labels at the left.
One solution is to increase  the value of PointNameSep by trial-and-errors; another is to set `PointName=none` and use `\uput`.
Both solutions are illustrated with this code:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{pstricks}
    \usepackage{pst-eucl}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,5)%
     \pstGeonode(1,1){A_i}
        \pstGeonode[PointName=A_j](1,2){Aj}
        \pstGeonode[PointName=R_{i,j,k,l},PointNameSep =1.85em](1,3){Rijkl}
        \pstGeonode[PointName=none](1,4){Sijkl}\uput{1pt}[r](Sijkl){$ S_{i,j,k,l} $}
    \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly it is not what I am looking for. :-)

Comment: @WeirdstressFunction: Could you be more precise about what you're looking for? The last solution I gave doesn't use PointNameSep.

Comment: The last solution is too verbose so I don't like it as well. :-)

Comment: If you don't intend to change parameters (colour of the dot, for instance), it's easy to turn it into a personal macro. Or you write to the author: it looks very much like a bug.